# Change LED for charging

Tags: notification-led

How can I change my LED to show colour, when it is charging. More specifically, how can I change these colours? I am using a rooted Sony Xperia E C1505. I do not want to use an app, for storage reasons (I have tiny storage on '/data)

Comment: Afraid without *using* an app, you can't accomplish much on Android – though some things are possible using the ones already *installed*.</hair-split-mode>. While I know there are some apps taking care for that, I'm not aware of other options. Be welcome, however, to check [this page](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings) for "LED" (multiple choices); maybe one of them is small enough to be worth considering.

Comment: Some phones(Nexus I think) does give options to change LED notification color for different tasks. IDK, if your phone support the options, do check for it.

Comment: @Izzy ok. I may manage a small app.

Comment: I've never used any of those (my LG P880 has no LED). I'd recommend starting with Lucky's advice (maybe you can do without installing an additional app); if that doesn't work out, please pick from the list I've linked. When you've solved your issue yourself, please don't forget to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) :) Good luck!

Comment: @Izzy I don't have these options. I tried an app that supports my phone, but it has not worked.

Comment: @Lucky do not have them options.

Comment: No more ideas from my end then, Dan – sorry.

Comment: @Izzy alright then.

Comment: Good luck still – even if it's calm right now. Remember the weather and the holidays, people might return :)

Comment: @Izzy will do.  I've got a holiday booked for a few weeks from now.